# ggpubr stat_compare_means: Show significance levels with two grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, visualization, ggpubr

I am trying to visualize significance levels (asterisks) with `ggpubr`'s `stat_compare_means()`. I encountered the following issue: As opposed to `compare_means()`, you cannot add a grouping variable to the comparison.
Example:

```
ggbarplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", add = "mean_se", color = "supp",
fill = "supp",position = position_dodge(0.8),add.params = list(group = "supp"))+
stat_compare_means(ref.group = "0.5", group.by = "supp",label = "p.signif")
```

[image: plot]
As you can see, the significance levels are not displayed above all the bars, but only above the different doses, because ggpubr doesn't differentiate between different supps.

Is there any way to compare to these (sub)sets as well?

Thank you

Comment: It does not seem to be easily possible according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/65) on the package repo. One solution is to put each "supp" in different facets.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
ToothGrowth %>% 
     mutate(gr=interaction(supp, dose, sep = " ")) %>% 
    {ggplot(data=.,aes(x = gr,  y = len, fill = supp)) +
            stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar") +
            stat_summary(aes(col = supp), fun.data = "mean_se", geom = "errorbar", width=0.6)+
            ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = combn(sort(unique(as.character(.$gr))),2, simplify = F),
                                  step_increase = 0.08,test = "wilcox.test", test.args = list(exact = FALSE))}
```

[image]

By adding `map_signif_level = TRUE` or `map_signif_level = c("***"=0.001, "**"=0.01, "*"=0.05),` you get 
[image]

Comment: please, where exactly should I add the `map_signif_level = c("***"=0.001, "**"=0.01, "*"=0.05)` or `map_signif_level = TRUE` to plot significance stars? Thank you

Comment: within the `ggsignif::geom_signif()` function